# Joomla menu: putting text BEFORE image

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu, joomla, joomla3.0

I'm building a website with a vertical drop-down menu. One of the menu items should contain an image and the menu title.
Joomla puts the image before the text, in the following way:

```
<li class="item-153 current active"><a class="menu_immagine" href="whatever" ><img src="whatever.png" alt="whatever" /><span class="image-title">whatever</span></a></li>
```

What I'd like to do is putting the text before the image, like this:

```
<li class="item-153 current active"><span class="image-title">whatever</span><a class="menu_immagine" href="whatever" ><img src="whatever.png" alt="whatever" /></a></li>
```

How can I do this in Joomla?

Thank you very much for your help...

Comment: You will need to make a template override for mod_menu. More information on template overrides can be found here: http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core

Comment: You're welcome. You should write you edited code as an answer and mark it as solved ;)

Comment: OK, I'll try to do that now ;) (I'm new...)

Comment: How do I mark it as solved?!?

Comment: Add it as an answer below in the "answer section" and then click the "tick icon" on the left hand side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Lodder, I made a template override. Then I modified the file myTemplate/html/mod_menu/default_component.php.

I changed this

```
if ($item->menu_image)
{
$item->params->get('menu_text', 1) ?
$linktype = '<img src="' . $item->menu_image . '" alt="' . $item->title . '" /> <span class="image-title">' . $item->title . '</span> ':
$linktype = '<img src="' . $item->menu_image . '" alt="' . $item->title . '" />';
}

else {
$linktype = $item->title;
}
```

to this:

```
if ($item->menu_image)
{
$item->params->get('menu_text', 1) ?
$linktype = '<span class="image-title">' . $item->title . '</span> <img src="' . $item->menu_image . '" alt="' . $item->title . '" /> ':
$linktype = '<img src="' . $item->menu_image . '" alt="' . $item->title . '" />';
}

else
{
$linktype = $item->title;
}
```

That's it! That was so easy, after all, that's a matter of knowing how to do it! ;)